# Converting a log or textfile to a dataframe using pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a text file where the data I want to be stored exists sequentially after each name I want to assign. Basically, I want to take a text file that looks like follows:

Fred
quiz1, B
quiz2, C
Suzie
quiz1, A
quiz2, B

and create a data frame that looks as follows

Name, Assignment, Grade
Fred, quiz1, B
Fred, quiz1, C
Suzie, quiz1, A
Suzie, quiz2, B
'''

Comment: Hi, I added a response with a python solution but I'd also add that if this is just for one file that you might be better off just opening the file up in a text editor that you can define a macro in (such as Emacs) and just run through it to replace the newlines after the name lines with a comma.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Do you have a specific problem? Stack Overflow is not meant for general "how do I do this/do it for me" type questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd 
from io import StringIO

# Create textfile
txtfile = StringIO("""Fred
quiz1, B
quiz2, C
Suzie
quiz1, A
quiz2, B""")

#use pandas to read in text file as a single column
df = pd.read_csv(txtfile, header=None, sep='\s\s+', engine='python')

#Use str split to seperate columns
df = df[0].str.split(',', expand=True)

#Use groupby with transform to take first value of the "name" column and copy down to the rest of the group
df[2] = df.groupby(df[1].isna().cumsum())[0].transform('first')

#drop the first record which has None.
df_out = df.dropna()
print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
       0   1      2
1  quiz1   B   Fred
2  quiz2   C   Fred
4  quiz1   A  Suzie
5  quiz2   B  Suzie
```

Comment: What is the `sep='\s\s+'` for?

Comment: That is a separator parameter, this is how I force the contents to load in a single column because, you don't have two consecutive spaces on a line.

Answer (score 2):

Here an example :

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = """
Fred
quiz1, B
quiz2, C
Suzie
quiz1, A
quiz2, B
Susy
quiz1, E
quiz2, F
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data),sep=',', names=['Assignment', 'Grade','Name'], header=None)
df['Name']= np.where(df['Grade'].isnull(),df['Assignment'],np.NaN)
df['Name'] = df['Name'].ffill()
print(df.dropna(subset=['Grade']))
```

Comment: `df["Name"] = df.Assignment[df.Grade.isna()]` also works instead of using `np.where`

Comment: @Stuart beat me to it by a minute

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not trying to load this file directly with pandas. Just read it line by line and create a new array that can be converted to a DataFrame.

```py
grades = []
with open("your_file.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f.read().split('\n'):
        if "," not in line:
            # should be a name line
            name = line
        else:
            # split into [test, grade] and append to grades with the name
            grades.append([name, line.split(',')[0].strip(), line.split(',')[1].strip()])
# convert to DataFrame
grades = pd.DataFrame(grades, columns=['Name', 'Assignment', 'Grade'])
```

Comment: `for line in f.read().split('\n'):` --> `for line in f` No need to make things more complicated than that. You could also use the csv module. I am curious why you are against reading the file with Pandas directly.

Comment: You're also splitting twice for seemingly no reason. You can just do `quiz, grade = line.split(',')`, eh.

Comment: I wouldn’t say I’m against reading it with Pandas, this way makes more sense to me just because it’s not a tabular file. And yes, you can create variables for quiz and grade if you don’t want to split twice, though they should still be stripped after the split.